# Nothing is shown in the asset library

Tags: asset-browser

I'm using Blender 3.4.1 and the issue keeps annoying me no matter how many times I restart Blender. The file browser works fine and the asset library path is set correctly, but the asset browser just doesn't show anything. I have tried with other folders but the problem still exists.

[image]

Comment: Just in case: did you mark them as assets? Just having shaders in a file is not enough, they need to be specifically marked as assets.

Comment: Having the same problem, did you find a fix?

Comment: I have the same problem? Anyone know what cause this?